# password protected in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, security, password-protection

I have this code (ASP.net VB.net):

```
Dim xx As Net.Mail.SmtpClient
xx.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
```

I'm not very sure but would the password stored there be ridiculously easy for a hacker to get?

If it was a standard windows form app, something like net reflector get the password with the click of a button, so how do I make it more secure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your really worried about it you can put it in the config file and use "[protected config file sections](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/3b5a1d1f-aa57-40d8-8607-fee0b2a8a6db)" to encrypt it.

In order to get the code the attacker would need to get the executable from the machine, not just the result of the page. In a well managed IIS server this is non-trivial (not impossible).

Answer (score 5):

Store the username and password in the app.config (Windows Forms app) or web.config (Web app) and encrypt the sections.  Pretty easy to do and secure...

Example here ==> http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/11/17/2572.aspx